# Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465

Tags: php, laravel, smtp

When I try to use Gmail SMTP for sending email via Laravel, I encounter the following error:

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection timed out)

It is the trace of the error

```
set_error_handler(function ($type, $msg) {
    throw new Swift_TransportException('Connection could not be established with host '.$this->params['host'].' :'.$msg);
});
```

Comment: Do you have the `openssl` extension enabled?

Comment: This can sometimes be because something is blocking the destination site! Could your firewall be getting in the way?

Comment: Yes OpenSSL is enabled

Comment: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018

Answer (score 0):

you need set the email config . enter this commands into your terminal

```
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear

php artisan config:cache
```